# Is there a better alternative to using GROUP BY in this scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is a short example what I have in my BDD:

```
Ref   | NameContact | CODE
SF005 | Toto        | SF
SF006 | Titi        | BC
SF005 | Toto        | SF
SF007 | Foo         | FB
SF006 | Bar         | BC
SF005 | Tata        | SF
SF005 | Tata        | SF
```

I like to get this:

```
Ref   | NameContact |CODE
SF005 | Toto        | SF
SF005 | Tata        | SF
```

I've tried to use `DISTINCT` but it doesn't work correctly. It works when I use `GROUP BY` with all named columns and `MAX()`. However, I have many columns and the query is very big. Is there is a better solution?

```
SELECT MAX(Ref),NameContact,Code FROM MyTable WHERE CODE = 'SF' GROUP BY NameContact,Code
```

Comment: What is the logic for your results?  I can think of many ways to get those results.

Comment: I need to get all ContactName without duplicate values for CODE = SF.

Comment: `SELECT distinct Ref,NameContact,Code FROM MyTable WHERE CODE = 'SF'`

Comment: What did you get when you used `DISTINCT` as far as I can tell, you should've gotten the same results.

Comment: When i use distinct on Ref |ContactName|Code i"ve duplicated values example i"ve Toto,Toto,Tata,Tata.

Comment: Why you don't like group by if it works?

Comment: Because i think it's a bad way and i think there is a better solution that listed all columns in my Select and in my Group By.

Comment: Try to think about your scenario. Even the fact that somebody asked you about the result means that it is not intention revealing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a sub-query adding a windowed row-number, you can select the first (or last, or median, or etc... ) row.

E.g.

```
SELECT Ref, NameContact, Code ... FROM 
    ( SELECT 
        Row-Number() OVER (PARTITION BY NameContact ORDER BY NameContact) AS RN,
        Ref, NameContact, Code ... 
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE CODE = 'SF') Windowed
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: I think you should add `NameContact,CODE` in `Partition by` and add `Ref` in `Order by`

Comment: It's not obvious from the example given which set of columns is meant to be unique and which just happen to be

Answer (score 3):

Since your `GROUP BY` query gives you the results you want (and is arguably the simplest way to write this query), one thing you can do to ease the pain of listing many columns in your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` is to expand your table in the SSMS object explorer and drag the `Columns` folder into your query editor, that will list out all the fields, comma separated for you.  Then you can cut out the one's you'll be aggregating/excluding.

Comment: All the years that I have worked with SSMS I didn't know you could do this! I've always just right-clicked and selected 'Script table as...' and copied & pasted the column names from the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT Ref, NameContact, Code, ... rest of the fields
FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NameContact
                            ORDER BY Ref DESC) AS rn,
         Ref, 
         NameContact,
         Code, 
         ... rest of the fields
  FROM MyTable 
  WHERE CODE = 'SF') AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

This will pick *exactly one* record for each `NameContact` partition: the one having the maximum `Ref` value.

**Note:** If you want the query to work for any `CODE` value, then you should also add `CODE` field in the `PARTITION BY` clause of `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: You'd still want to use a `DISTINCT` with this. Otherwise you will have two `Tata` records.

Comment: When i execute your query i've duplicate values in my result. I'm curious but what is the goal of OVER Partition ? I've never used yet

Comment: @Quentin Do you have `WHERE CODE = 'SF'`  in your query?

Comment: I see you have edited your answer, your answer and the answer of Caleth work good !